# When subsetting a dataframe during a for loop, I get a zero row data frame instead of one row as intended?

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I'm attempting to create a vector containing a basketball player's EFG% for a range of seasons, i.e. if the player shot 45% and then 50% over two seasons, the vector would look like (.45, .50). I'm using a for loop to iterate through a user-inputed range of seasons. I scrape a data frame of all players in a season, then attempt to subset that data frame into just the row of the player I want to know about. However, when doing so I get a zero-row data frame instead of one row. When performing the same operation outside of the for loop by hand, it works perfectly. My function code is below.

```
efgVectorFunction <- function(playerName, firstSeason, lastSeason) {
  require(ballr)
  emptyVector <- numeric(0)
  for(i in firstSeason:lastSeason) {
    seasonStats <- NBAPerGameStatistics(season = i)
    playerSeasonStats <- subset(seasonStats, seasonStats$player == "playerName")
    seasonEFG <- as.numeric(playerSeasonStats[ ,-c(1:17, 19:31)])
    efgVector <- c(emptyVector, seasonEFG)
  }
  return(efgVector)
}
```

The issue is that this code returns an [NA] since the playerSeasonStats subset ends up with zero rows. Outside the for loop, this code works fine:

```
test <- NBAPerGameStatistics(season = 2018)
testSingle <- subset(test, test$player == "Russell Westbrook")
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't `== "playerName"` be : `== playerName` ?

Comment: And shouldn't `efgVector <- c(emptyVector, seasonEFG)` be `efgVector <- c(efgVector, seasonEFG)` with `efgVector` initialized outside loop? Consider `sapply` or `vapply` to avoid bookkeeping.

Comment: I applied both of yours' changes and the function works as expected. Thanks much.